# Visual Studio 2008 hangs when opening project under Source Control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project, source-control-explorer

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I've just recently gotten a problem where Visual Studio will hang when loading a project that's under source control.  I can load an individual project that's not under source control just fine.  However, when trying to load a project that *is* under SC, the progress bar in the lower right corner will get all the way filled, and then everything just stops.  I let VS run overnight thinking that is just needs some time to think about it, but it apparently has stopped liking me and has now decided to be difficult.

The only thing that changed is I pulled out my second video card.  Before yanking the video card, VS was all warm and fuzzy and working, but after the removal, it's all hissy and difficult.

Update:  I played around with it a little more, and I can open up individual files (like .cs files), but I can't get the .sln file to open......

Update 2: I tried repairing the installation, and that didn't help.  Also, VS hangs when I try to get a specific version of a program from Source Control.  Looks like I'm going to have to uninstall and reinstall.

Update 3:  After fitzing and futzing around with uninstalling and reinstalling it a few times (and completely wiping out the install folder), I got the TFS / Source Control stuff fixed, but now I've got a new problem.  Now I get a "Package Load Failure.  Package 'ReportDesignerPackage' has failed to load properly (GUID = {11b8c903-8ffd-4dfc-87ce-f6a8d77af6b}).  So....still not working correctly.

Update 4:  After much pain and frustration (along with gouging my eyeballs out with forks), I decided to disable the packages that were not loading correctly, and it doesn't appear to have any effect on Visual Studio.  No the most ideal solution, but it works.  A month later (with HEAVY usage), and everything seems to be working just fine and dandy.

Answer (score 1):

Does control return to VS if you press Escape ?
If it does then try Alt-Space-M and then use your left or right arrows and hopefully a dialog box will appear that VS is waiting for a response!

I had this exact problem for days which started after I swapped my primary monitor (I have 2) so a dialog box (like Get latest version on a TFS project) that was asking me to confirm if I wanted to overwrite all files etc was basically off-screen.

VERY annoying but so satisfying that it wasn't anything serious with my configuration!